# Animate list selector color

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I have this listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
    android:divider="#fff"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0.9dp"
    android:listSelector="#80ED84"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

</ListView>
```

It has a list selector that shows green color when an item inside the list is selected, what i want to create is to fade in the color when the item is selected, instead of it just appearing, how could i animate only the list selector?

I have tried this:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, final View view, final int i, long i2) {

                  Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SendActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                  view.startAnimation(anim);

            }
            });
```

But that animates the entire listview, and not just the list selector, how could i modify the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must create an XML file for your list selector that you place in `/drawable-nodpi` and adjust the values of `android:enterFadeDuration` and `android:exitFadeDuration` to your desired fade animation duration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <item android:drawable="@color/a_lighter_green_color" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/your_green_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

Please note that with this technique, which is the proper way to do it, the animation will only be visible on API level 11 and above (Android 3+), but today it means more than 80% of devices. Older devices will see the correct color but no fade animation.

Comment: Should i link the listSelector to the animation like this? : android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_animation"

Comment: Yes. You can also do it in your application theme to impact all ListViews.